# Java - byte[] to int conversion and vice versa

Tags: java, python

I am porting some php code as well as python code, which are two functions. The purpose of them is parsing an integer to a byte array and vice versa. However it worked for a while, but now I get invalid integer errors.

I got the following python snippet which I converted to Java:

```
def _deAdjustId(val):
    if sys.version_info >= (3,0):
        valEnc = val.encode('latin-1') if type(val) is str else val
    else:
        valEnc = val
    return int(binascii.hexlify(valEnc), 16)
```

And my Java code:

```
private static int deAdjustId(byte[] val) {
    String valEnc;
    try {
        valEnc = new String(val, "iso-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        valEnc = new String(val);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(BinAscii.hexlify(valEnc.getBytes()), 16);
}
```

The error given here is the following:

```
caught exception: Invalid int: "325FC398C3AB"
```

Does this mean that the integer value is too big, or what is the problem?

Comment: Java int is signed 32-bit. That is more than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`valEnc.getBytes()` will convert the String to bytes using the host platform's default encoding, which is going to be either UTF-16LE (in Windows) or UTF-8 (all other platforms, including yours).

Your String contains ISO 8859-1 characters, but any of those characters with values above 127 are being *decoded* as multiple bytes by `valEnc.getBytes()`.  To fix this, use `valEnc.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`.  Then you will be guaranteed to get one byte per character.

However, that raises the question of why you would bother using String in the first place.  You already have a byte array whose bytes each represent an ISO 8859-1 character.  You should remove `valEnc` from your method completely.

In fact, there is no reason to convert the bytes to hex and then parse them.  You can just convert four bytes to an int with this:

```
return ByteBuffer.wrap(val).getInt();
```

See the [documentation for ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for more information, particularly the [getInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt--) method.

**Update:** It seems `val` has no guarantees regarding its size, so you'll want to account for that:

```
if (val == null) {
    return 0;
}

if (val.length >= 4) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(val).getInt();
}

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buffer.position(4 - val.length);
buffer.put(val);
buffer.rewind();
return buffer.getInt();
```

Comment: Well, that gives me a BufferUnderflowException... Maybe you can take a look here, it was a working code but that one didn't work anymore after there were illegal characters which weren't be able to get parsed into an int

https://github.com/gi097/WhatsApi-Android/blob/1287cd3fc5619b760433bdcddb0d083aa4f3ce45/app/src/main/java/nl/giovanniterlingen/whatsapp/WhatsApi.java

Comment: A BufferUnderflowException should only happen if your array has fewer than 4 bytes.  I've updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: Really helpful! Thank you. And what about reverse order? From the int back to the original byte[] array? ByteBuffer can handle that too?

Comment: Yes.  `ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(someIntValue).array()`.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't provide me the result I need.

Comment: It's hard to provide assistance without more details than that.  What int value did you use, and what bytes were you expecting to get?

Comment: Well, it's also unclear to me. As you can see on my github, I have two functions called adjustId(int) and deAdjustId(byte[]), deAdjustId() should return an int from a byte array, which AdjustId() can convert back to the original byte array. See the code here (last two functions) https://github.com/gi097/WhatsApi-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nl/giovanniterlingen/whatsapp/WhatsApi.java

You can also take a look at the same function names which I tried to port from PHP which uses a little different method:

https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/blob/master/src/func.php

Answer (score 0):

Python `int` is like `BigInteger` in Java:

```
private static BigInteger deAdjustId(byte[] val) {
    String valEnc;
    try {
        valEnc = new String(val, "iso-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        valEnc = new String(val);
    }
    return new BigInteger(BinAscii.hexlify(valEnc.getBytes()), 16);
}
```

or even:

```
private static BigInteger deAdjustId(byte[] val) {
    return new BigInteger(val);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks! but the return type must be an int due encryption and all stuff, see here:

https://github.com/gi097/WhatsApi-Android/blob/1287cd3fc5619b760433bdcddb0d083aa4f3ce45/app/src/main/java/nl/giovanniterlingen/whatsapp/WhatsApi.java

See the last two methods.

Comment: @JohnDoe But then the array size may not exceed 4 bytes, what it obviously does in your case...